# Stopping jQuery equal height divs from calculating hidden content

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using the following jQuery to giv certain divs with the id's `#main`, `#sidebar`, `#side-event` equal height. On most pages, I am using `.hide();` to toggle information within the content section of the site. The problem is when JS caluclates the height of the #main div, it's calculating all of the hidden content as well, which I do not want. How can I alter my code so that the height is equal to the tallest div, and not include the hidden information in the equation? In addition I added the code I am using to hide the information upon page load. Here is my page from the site for referencing the issue. Hoping someone can help me with this issue.

http://shadowfaxdigital.com/cdi/events/mba-essentials-business-design-workshops/

Calculating height:

```
    $("#main, #sidebar, #side-event").addClass("heights");

    var highestCol = Math.max($('#main').height(),$('#sidebar').height(), $("#side-event").height());

    $('.heights').height(highestCol);
```

Code used to hide the content in the toggles:

```
          //jQuery toggle
            $(".toggle_container").hide();
            $("h2.trigger").click(function(){
                $(this).toggleClass("active").next().slideToggle("slow");
            });
```

Comment: if I got negative vote because I didn't provide enough info I apologize, however, I think this is a valid problem that could use a real resolution.

Answer (score 0):

It's not entirely clear what exactly you're asking for help with.  `.height()` will only include the height of child elements that take up space in the layout.  So an item that was hidden with `.hide()` will be marked `display:none` and will not be included in the height of any parent elements.  But an item that has a zero `opacity` or `visibility:hidden` will take up space in the layout and will be included in a parent's height.

In jQuery, you can see if anything is visible with:

```
$("#main").is(":visible");
```

Or, you can put it directly into a selector to only include visible items:

```
$("#main:visible")
```

So, you could change your code to something like this if you only want to include the visible items in your selector:

```
var visibleItems = $("#main:visible, #sidebar:visible, #side-event:visible");
var highestCol = Math.max.apply(this, visibleItems.map(function() {
    return $(this).height();
}).get());
```

Comment: sorry for the confusion. tried your code and it didn't seem to work. here is a link to my issue. I am currently using my code, and you will see that the sidebar stretches the length of the hidden content in the `#main` div.

http://shadowfaxdigital.com/cdi/events/mba-essentials-business-design-workshops/

Comment: @chris_s - we don't know your page.  Please gives us some guidance around the page.  What object in the page is hidden that you think is being included in your calculation that you don't want included.

Comment: @chris_s - In your page, `#main` has a `style.height` set on it of `1389px` and a CSS rule that sets it to `940px` if there is no `style.height` value.  The `style.height` value is not because of the content in `#main`, it's because some code is setting that height value on `#main`.

Comment: the 940px on `#main` is its width. the content in toggles (in the content section of the page) is what is being used as the height, as if the content was not hidden. but as you can tell, upon page load, that content has `display: none` set until you click on the red links.

Comment: @chris_s - what code is setting the height of `#main` to `1389px`?  You have not included that code in your question and that seems to be the code that has the problem.

Comment: the jQuery code is in the original post is what is setting that height. It's taking into account the height of all the hidden content in the toggles, and making that the full width of the `#main` and `#sidebar` divs

Answer (score 0):

you can add the [visible](http://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/) selector, this will check if the element has display:none or opacity:0

```
var $sfd = jQuery.noConflict();
var cols = $sfd('#main:visible, #sidebar:visible, #side-event:visible');
var maxHeight = 0;
$(cols).each(function(){
    $(this).addClass('heights');
    maxHeight = Math.max($(this).height(), maxHeight);
});

$sfd('.heights').height(maxHeight);
```

Comment: matt, tried this and didn't seem to work. I posted a link to my site in the other answer comment section, where you can see the issue with my code. hope this helps resolving it. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue aswell today. Googled alot and found this thread. Seems this wasn't properly solved, therefore I'm posting my solution:
My issue was that the height-adjusting script was calculating the heights before the elements were successfully hid with jQuery, I therefore copied my height-equalizing script into a $(document).ready(function() {} );

Like this:

```
$(document).ready(function()
   {
     if ($('.sidebar').height() < $('#mainwindow').height())
   {
    var mainwindowHeight = $('#mainwindow').height();
    $(".sidebar").css('height', mainwindowHeight+8+'px');
   }
  });
```

This solved it for me.
Hope this helps someone.